# How to distinguish x-rays and gamma rays in the electromagnetic spectrum between the wavelenghts of 10^-13 to 10^-10?

Tags: waves

I found out that x-rays and gamma rays overlap in the electromagnetic spectrum between the wavelengths of 10^-13 to 10^-10 in my physics textbook. However, i found no answer in my book and other sources. So, how to differentiate between x-rays and gamma-rays in this wavelengths.

Comment: See wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray#Distinction_from_X-rays

Answer (score 1):

"Gamma-ray" and "X-ray" are purely labels for photnos in different energy ranges / wavelengths. The is no strict definition of where one ends and the other begins. But an 'x-ray' of $\lambda=10^{-11}m$ is *exactly* the same thing as a 'gamma-ray' of  $\lambda=10^{-11}m$: they are both just photons with  $\lambda=10^{-11}m$.

The difference in terminology is largely a matter of production mechanism or detection method. If you have an X-ray detector whose sensitive range extends to that wavelength,  you might call the photons detected X-rays. Of you have a gamma ray telescope detecting the range photon at the bottom end of its sensitive range, you would call it a gamma ray. A high energy photon from an X-ray machine would be called an X-ray. A lower energy photon from radioactiv decay would be called a gamma-ray. But the physical particle (photon) is completely indifferent to our terminology.

Comment: Gammas are produced by nuclear transitions, x-rays by electronic transitions. Wavelengths overlap.

Comment: Not in astrophysics: gamma-rays can be produced by various mechanisms that have nothing to do with nuclear transitions.

Comment: Interesting. Different definitions for different disciplines is not unusual of course.

Comment: @Jon Custer. In my case Gamna rays and x rays differed by their origin as such: x outer layers electronic transitions; gamma nuclear and inner core transitions. :)